# Java version issue

Tags: java, command-line, centos, java-8, version

I installed jdk-8u91-linux-x64.rpm onto my CentOS box, got no errors.

However, when I write the command it is still displaying Java 7, not the Java 8 I installed.

> $ java -version
>
> java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea" OpenJDK Runtime
> Environment (rhel-2.3.4.1.el6_3-x86_64) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
> (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

I need to leave Java7 files, but need java to use 8.

Comment: you most probably need to update your `$PATH` variable. I am not sure how CentOS manages environment variables and software alternatives, but you might want to look into this topic. Maybe [this](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaRuntimeEnvironment) helps.

Answer (score 1):

You missing the following:

```
cd /opt/jdk1.8.xxx/
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.xxx/bin/java 2
alternatives --config java

alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /opt/jdk1.8.xxx/bin/jar 2
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.8.xxx/bin/javac 2
alternatives --set jar /opt/jdk1.8.xxx/bin/jar
alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.8.xxx/bin/javac
```

For more information:
http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/

Answer (score 0):

Run this and it will find all instances of java installed:

> update-alternatives --config java

Then select the version to default to.

/Thread

Answer (score 0):

To see which version(s) of JDKs are installed, run the below command:

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

Use `java -version` , to see which Java version you are currently using.

To use the latest OpenJDK 8, follow the following steps to install and set OpenJDK 8 the default Java version:

Enter the following command, type user password and hit Enter to continue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
```

Update system package cache with the command :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install OpenJDK 8 by running :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

To make it the default version, enter :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select OpenJDK 8 by typing the selection number against it.

Also, set default Java Compiler by running :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Now run

```
java -version
```

to check if Java is updated.

Reference:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-openjdk-8-ubuntu-14-04-12-04-lts/

Comment: There is no `update-java-alternatives` in CentOS.